# OpenMP offloading tasks to Intel MIC

Tags: fortran, openmp, xeon-phi, offloading

I am trying to offload an expensive loop in my program to Intel MIC.
The part of the code is:

```
!$omp target map(to:coor,sigma_const,clase) map(tofrom:ener1,ener2)
!$omp parallel private(i,j,fdummy1,k,l,fdummy2,fdummy3,fdummy4,fdummy5,dist)
!$omp do reduction(+:ener1)
do i=1,num_res-2
  do j=i+2,num_res

   fdummy1=coor(i,1,qk)-coor(j,1,qk)
   fdummy2=coor(i,2,qk)-coor(j,2,qk)
   fdummy3=coor(i,3,qk)-coor(j,3,qk)
   dist=sqrt(fdummy1*fdummy1+fdummy2*fdummy2+fdummy3*fdummy3)

   fdummy1=sigma_const(i,j)                                                                                                                               
   write(6,*) 'fdum',fdummy1
   k=clase(i)
   l=clase(j)
   fdummy2=fdummy1*fdummy1      ! 2
   fdummy3=fdummy2*fdummy2      ! 4
   fdummy4=fdummy2*fdummy3      ! 6
   fdummy5=fdummy4*fdummy4      ! 12

   fdummy1=fdummy5-fdummy4

   ener1=ener1+eps_const(k,l)*fdummy1

  enddo
enddo
!$omp end do

!$omp do reduction(+:ener2)
do i=1,num_res-1
   fdummy1=coor(i,1,qk)-coor(i+1,1,qk)
   fdummy2=coor(i,2,qk)-coor(i+1,2,qk)
   fdummy3=coor(i,3,qk)-coor(i+1,3,qk)
   dist=sqrt(fdummy1*fdummy1+fdummy2*fdummy2+fdummy3*fdummy3)
      fdummy1=(dist-r_cero)
      fdummy2=fdummy1*fdummy1
      ener2=ener2+fdummy2
enddo
!$omp end do
!$omp end parallel
!$omp end target
```

When I printout the value of sigma_const array I get 0, I don't know the
reason because I map the array to the MIC. I am 
confused about the order of `!$omp target map/!$omp target` directives with 
respect to the `!$omp parallel` one. In some examples, I saw on internet,
people use first target directives outside parallel regions but they
can also use target inside the parallel region (see for instance: https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-visual-fortran-compiler-for-windows/topic/516606).

Another thing, is it possible that the MIC keeps the values of some arrays
like sigma_const,clase (which don't change during the simulation) so that 
I don't need to transfer them at each simulation time step?

Comment: Your nesting appears correct. You have a block of code that executes on the device (`target` region), within which you have a `parallel` region. Having it the other way round will start a parallel region on the host and one device region per host thread (not what you want, I guess). You can create a data region on the device using `target data` and have multiple `target` regions within it. The data on the device will persist and `target update` could be used to sync between the host and the device when necessary.

Comment: The code on Intel's site uses a host parallel region to start as many threads as coprocessors are there in the system and then spawns a device region from each host thread. This allows multiple separate `target` regions to execute in parallel, which cannot be done using a single thread only (as OpenMP still does not support asynchronous execution of device constructs).

Comment: so in the present example one target before the parallel construct is enough to execute the entire parallel region on the MIC? Thanks.